# Returning array indexes in a Collection while using Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

This is the first time I am trying to use the *new* Stream API in Java 1.8 and I have to admit that I have some problem understanding it...

Basically, let's say I have an int array containing same values. For example:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Now, I'd like to use the Stream API and store in a List the indexes of this intArray where the value is higher than 3.

This is what my code looks like:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, intArray.length)
                                 .filter(i -> intArray[i] > 3)
                                 .sorted()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I get a compilation failure saying "The method collect(Supplier, ObjIntConsumer, BiConsumer) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector >)".

I'd like indexes to contain 3 and 4.

Comment: An `IntStream` is a Stream of primitive `int` values, not of `Integer` objects. So when you create a `List`, those primitives values must be boxed to their corresponding `Integer` (because there is no `IntList`, i.e. a List which would hold primitive values). So you need to call `boxed()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should box your `IntStream` into a `Stream<Integer>` :

```
List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, intArray.length)
                             .filter(i -> intArray[i] > 3)
                             .sorted()
                             .boxed()
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that there's no point in `.sorted()` call

Answer (score 0):

You could use different logic:

```
int[] c = {-1}; // array is effectively final
Arrays.stream(intArray)
  .map(n -> ++c[0] >= 0 && n > 3 ? c[0] : -1)
  .filter(n -> n > -1)
  .boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This turns every n > 3 into its index then filters out the rest, which avoids a sort.